# Cannot drop empty database in mariadb

Tags: innodb, mariadb

I am having trouble dropping a database on my server
innodb-file-per-table is set to true

We previously had a huge table (1TB) which we used a drop table command. This result i believe was successfully completed but left a file called #sql-ib116.ibd in the directory.

We have completely cleared out the db, but when i issue a drop database dbname, it seems to be stuck in the "closing tables" phase

I then tried to create a frm equivalent and drop the table using this guide to no avail
https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/get-rid-of-orphaned-innodb-temporary-tables-the-right-way/

Im running out of server space and would ideally like manually remove the idb file
If i delete the file from the datadir, will this cause issues? im not worried about the data in this idb file. I also many other databases in this mariadb instance, will deleting affect the remaining?

Any ideas would be fantastic!
Thanks

p.s. i just ran the command SELECT * FROM information_schema.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES where name regexp 'dbname/'
and i can still see the table
dbname/#sql-ib116
dbname/#sql-ib53761
when i do show tables it still returns no values

Comment: Avoid touching database files directly. Always. The forums of people who diverge from that fill these forums with sad tales of data loss. What MariaDB version? What innodb settings do you have? What table cache settings do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would prefer not to delete files manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would prefer not to delete files manually. I am currently using 10.3.18-MariaDB.    innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size 134217728 
innodb_buffer_pool_size 429496729600 
innodb_log_file_size 16106127360 
innodb_disable_sort_file_cache OFF
innodb_ft_cache_size 8000000
innodb_ft_result_cache_limit 2000000000
innodb_ft_total_cache_size 640000000

Comment: Apologies on the formatting, i couldnt work out how to make it cleaner, predominantly the settings are default. Are there any particular settings you after after?

Comment: you can edit your existing question.

Comment: any other ideas guys?